# Merge data frame by count in R

Tags: r, merge, subset

I have two data frame below.

```
set.seed(12345)

df1 <- data.frame(
  y1 = sample(rep(c(0:1),length.out = 50)),
  y2 = sample(rep(c(0:1),length.out = 50)),
  y3 = sample(rep(c(0:1),length.out = 50)),
  y4 = sample(rep(c(0:1),length.out = 50)),
  y5 = sample(rep(c(0:1),length.out = 50)),
  y6 = sample(rep(c(0:1),length.out = 50))
)

df2 <- data.frame(x = c("y1","y2","y1:y2","y2:y3:y4","y5","y6"))
```

I want to merge this two data frame but the result of the merge will show the count of "1's" for each elemets. My other problem is that in the second data frame, some columns have more than one element separated by ":". This will make it hard for me to do this automatically. Below is the table I want to achieve

```
        x count
1       y1    25
2       y2    25
3    y1:y2    11
4 y2:y3:y4     8
5       y5    25
6       y6    25
```

Comment: What do you mean by `y1:y2` count?

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Comment: I think based on the `count` for `y1:y2`, it seems that `y2:y3:y4` should be 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could get the column wise sum of 'df1' with `colSums`.  Identify the elements of 'x' that has `:` using `grep`.  Then, we `split` the 'x' column based on the index ('i1'), subset the 'df1' columns in each `list` element, use `Reduce` with `&` so that we get only `TRUE` when all the elements in the same row are 1. Get the `sum`, and create the 'count' column based on the 'v1' object created.

```
v1 <- colSums(df1)
i1 <- grep(':', df2$x)
v1[i1] <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df2$x[i1]), ':'), 
           function(x) sum(Reduce(`&`,df1[x])))
df2$count <- v1
```

Comment: Nice solution. Was thinking of something similar.

Comment: +1 really nice! I think I would keep it as a one liner `v1 <- sapply(strsplit(setNames(as.character(df2$x), as.character(df2$x)), ':'), 
                 function(x) sum(Reduce(`&`,df1[x])))` although maybe using `colSums`first and then only using the `sapply` + `sum(reduce)` when needed may be more efficient.